# Solved: Increasing Token Lifetime in OpenIddict for ABP Framework and Angular

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, timeout, abp-framework

I'm working on an Angular application using the ABP Framework with Entity Framework Core. After user logout, we are attempting to refresh the token, but we encounter a 500 Internal Server Error. This issue manifests in both the console and network tabs of the developer tools. Here are the error messages we receive:

- Console: Error refreshing token HttpErrorResponse {headers:
  HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: 'OK', url:
  'https://localhost:44351/connect/token', ok: false, ...}
- Network: A
  failed XHR request to https://localhost:44351/connect/token with a
  500 status code.

We suspect that this might be related to a timeout configuration, but we are not sure where to look or how to configure this properly.

What we've tried:

Checked server logs, but the information was inconclusive.
Verified that the database is accessible and there are no apparent connectivity issues.

Questions:

1. What are the common causes for a 500 error when refreshing tokens in an ABP Framework application?
2. Where in the ABP Framework or Angular
   configuration can I set or check the timeout for token refresh
   calls?
3. Are there any best practices for handling token refresh in
   Angular with the ABP Framework that I should be aware of?

Any
insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Attached below
are screenshots of the errors in both the console and network tabs.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your initial token is probably expiring after 15 minutes and the oidc library is trying to refresh it. Check if you have refresh token enabled on your identity provider and if your client is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Increasing Token Lifetime in OpenIddict for ABP Framework and Angular

The issue was resolved by adjusting the token lifetimes in the OpenIddict server configuration. Here's the code snippet showing the changes:

```
PreConfigure<OpenIddictServerBuilder>(builder =>
{
    // Other configurations...

    // Increased the lifetime of authorization code and access token
    builder.SetAuthorizationCodeLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(6));
    builder.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(6));

    // Other configurations...
});
```

By increasing the SetAuthorizationCodeLifetime and SetAccessTokenLifetime from 1 hour to 6 hours, the application now allows a longer period for the user to refresh the token without encountering a 500 error due to a token timeout.

This adjustment can be done in the startup configuration of your .NET Core application where you configure the OpenIddict server options.

Note:
It's important to choose appropriate lifetimes for your tokens based on the security requirements of your application. Longer lifetimes are more convenient for users but can potentially increase security risks.

I hope this helps anyone who might be facing similar issues!